# Android Studio, making a text based game

Tags: java, android, text

My first android app I'm creating, a text based game. Everything is looking great so far with functionality. I'm just wondering 2 things, one, is there a way to control how the new activity opens in the screen (new activities open from the center of the screen on my app, takes about a half second), and second, its it better to have each button pressed choice open a new activity or is there a better way to clear the screen and use the if and else commands in java.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your current code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think as for the first part, you may want to use animation on transition between activities/fragments.

You do want to read more about fragments as i think it will solve your second question.

[Check this small tutorial for the animation part.](https://developerlife.com/2008/08/05/android-animation-framework/)

[Check docs for fragments.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Good luck.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14390288)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, I'll edit the answer later.